# Temporary table delegated from a view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored proc that builds a temporary table made up of dates (a loop builds the table).
I need to have a view that joins onto that temporary table.
Unfortunately, due to the stupidness of the system combined with bad design by whomsoever made the database, it absolutely must be a view, and it needs to do this join in said view. I don't want to get into an argument over whether the architecture is correct, as I have absolutely no control over it.

My question is: is there any way at all to get access to something that will do a loop from a view? Or potentially some super-cool way of building a table of dates without using a loop - that would be awesome too.

Otherwise I'll just hide a statically created date table in their database somewhere and hope that they don't notice or something.

Edit: The loop goes something like this:

```
declare @years table (
    year date,
    label nvarchar(6)
)

declare @d date
set @d = '20060101'
while(@d < '20400101')
begin
    insert into @years select dateadd(month, 6, @d),
    'FY' + CONVERT(nvarchar(4), year(@d))
    set @d = DATEADD(year, 1, @d)
end

select * from @years
```

Comment: What does your loop look like? Maybe it can be refactored. Ideas: a view can call a table-valued function. Can you change your sproc to one of those, or create one that calls it?

Comment: A date table isn't necessarily a bad thing, here is one of many articles on their benefit: http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/

Comment: @AdamWenger I absolutely agree - I make date tables all the time when I'm building data warehouses. Unfortunately I'd rather not go there this time.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I've posted the code - I'll take a look at table-valued functions, that might be a good alternative.

Comment: @Blorgbeard That looks perfect - if you would care to post that as an answer I'll accept it, since you've answered how to delegate to a loop in a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two alternatives:

Instead of a view, use a user defined table function.  This gives you more flexibility on what you can do.

You can stash a date table.  You can also create one with a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2013-01-01' as date) as thedate
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, thedate)
      from dates
      where thedate <= '2013-01-31'
     )
select *
from dates;
```

Comment: +1 - Very cool, and interesting to learn. I'm using Blorgbeard's suggestion at the moment as I prefer to have a date function available for other uses, but if he doesn't turn it into an answer I'll have a play with this and probably accept.

Comment: I won't make my comment an answer, since this one pretty much covers it with "use a user defined table function" :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard Slightly different since he suggested it instead of a view, but I can respect that.